# can i allow malicious code to run on my site?

Tags: javascript, iframe

i m trying to create a small system where developers can write some code and that can be run by any other user.

if that code runs in some other user's session then it will privacy concerns as session data can be stolen

i could sandbox the code using an iframe but every pieace of code can have their own session data which again demands infinite iframes so i ll have to setup subdomains for each of the iframe

here is one way that i think which can suffice all the purposes

```
((window, document) => {
    // malicious code
    console.log(window, document)
})({}, {})
```

if i scope the code this way and give them a way to access only their data.

does this have any threats ?

all types of opinoins and tweaks are welcomed .
please help

Comment: Anything in the browser is accessible by anyone. Do NOT try to implement something like this with a front end language.

Comment: @Dementic i understand. but the idea i have, is such that code has to run :P. can you please write small snippet ? how this can be dangerous ? some hack ? some malicious code ?

Answer (score 4):

> here is one way that i think which can suffice all the purposes

No, that's not remotely sufficient. I suggest reading up on the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

You don't need infinite subdomains, but you do need a domain dedicated to just this user-provided code. Then put the code in an `iframe` with [sandbox options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox). For instance, here's the `iframe` that Stack overflow's Stack Snippets use:

```html
<iframe
    id="snpte-box-edit-result"
    name="071f00d0-f927-46e0-a9c5-872b42751f46"
    sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts"
    class="snippet-box-edit snippet-box-result"
    frameborder="0"
></iframe>
```

That's served from `https://stacksnippets.net`, not `stackoverflow.com`.

The key bits there are:

- The `sandbox` attribute activating the content security policy (CSP) and passlisting only the things Snippets should allow (forms, modals, and scripts). Everything else is blocked by default.
- Serving it from a domain used only for that purpose, not for other purposes.
- Not running the code unless the user explicitly requests it. In the case of Stack Snippets, that's via the **Run code snippet** button. The snippet does not run if the user does not click that button.

(I think serving it via HTTPS is also important. It's best practice in any case.)

Doing that **does not** guarantee that malicious code won't run (you are, after all, explicitly allowing it to run). But it tries to restrict the things the malicious code can do.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but i have one more purpose. that code can have its session data. which cant be excuted this way .

Comment: @Harkal - What kind of session information do you need to allow? You'll probably need to inject it into the code directly or similar.

Comment: basically the idea is => developers can write code | non developers can use it and allow it to run on their profile. code can have some feature or utility. so in order to fetch profile details or cache data. that code can have some session data.

Comment: visit the docs once => https://developers.famenun.com/

Comment: this is a huge project that i m working for last 3 years :P

Comment: @Harkal - As I said, I think you'll need to inject those details into the code (or provide them via an HTTP API or similar). And **beware**, what you're describing is **really** susceptible to abuse. You'll need to be extremely vigilant.

Comment: i see. i have talked to people about it. and i m still working upon sandboxing code without iframes. thank you for the repliles and anwer

Answer (score 2):

```js
((window, document, globalThis) => {
    'use strict';
    // malicious code
    console.log(window, document, globalThis); // null, null, null
    (async () => {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(function() {
        window = this;
        document = this.document;
        globalThis = this;
        r();
      }, 1));
      console.log(window, document, globalThis);
    })()
})(null, null, null)
```

Is already enough to fill the vars again with the original values.

There are several other ways to get the original window. You could create an iframe-element with `src="about:blank"`, append it to the DOM and access the `iframe.contentWindow.parent` property. Which will be the original `window` again.

```js
((window) => { // in case document is not null'd
  let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "about:blank";
  document.body.append(iframe);
  console.log(iframe.contentWindow.parent == globalThis);
})(null)
```

And if you block to much, nothing would be possible anymore.

You could also make use of [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). They are not allowed to access the DOM and/or Cookies/Storage.

Comment: okay i see . let me think something more solid and i ll add it to question. thank you for the answer. you knowlege is amazing